# What is the purpose of Node.js ? [eg: while implementing a graph algorithm on data set available on a server]

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, dataset

I have been using JS for simple front-end scripting for a while now, but am absolutely new to Node.js. After some surfing, I found out certain stuff about Node.js that it is fast, event-driven,uses modules, can be used both on server and client side, can be run from command line, etc.

As a project, the following task has been given to me:
"To develop a graph algorithm (such as minimum spanning tree) in javascript using node.js. Use the larger of the following graphs as inputs: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/ " [the link contains data from various network sites organised as nodes and edges and stored in .txt files]

Now I know how to implement a graph algorithm in a language (such as C), can even do it in JS using arrays. But I need some help regarding the "using node.js" part of the problem. What is its purpose in the problem ? Which of its features should I look up ?

Comment: I’d say, the use of Node.js in this particular task is to learn writing Node.js code.

Comment: @Xufox the attached link contains LARGE data [some graphs contain more than a million nodes and about 30+ million edges]. Does that anyhow imply the usage of node.js (like directly 'getting' the data from their server or smthing like that)

Comment: Have you done any of your own research on what node.js is and how it would apply to your problem before coming here?  It does not appear so.

Comment: node.js serves the same purpose that PHP, Perl, Java or Python do.  They are scripting run-time environments that can be used either to code back-end servers or to develop stand-alone apps.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've done a bit of research on Node.js as I briefed in the question. Its just I don't understand its application in the specified problem. I could write a solution for the same by using just JS right ? So,  I dont undrstand why node.js has been mentioned.

Comment: No, you can't write it in just JS.  You need a run-time environment for the JS like a browser or node.js.  Plus, JS the language by itself can't even communicate with the outside world - it has no networking, no file system access, nothing - it's just a pure language.  node.js is a Javascript environment PLUS a run-time environment that contains networking, file system access and a whole host of other features in the run-time library.  Imagine trying to solve your problem in just straight C with no standard library.  You couldn't get data from anywhere, you couldn't display anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok. Thanks a lot :) I'm learning node.js already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically JS was  made to run inside a browser.

Node.js is actually a javascript runtime invokable. You can invoke it from commandline. This means you can execute files of code from commandline like many other languages which you might be already familiar with. Beyond, that there is nothing much from your context.

But, yes it is fast, event-based, async and like server-scripting languages has server-handling capabilities inbuilt. That said it can be used for non-server contexts as well. Like computation in your case.

Comment: Thanks. But the attached link contains LARGE data [some graphs contain more than a million nodes and about 30+ million edges]. Does that anyhow imply the usage of node.js (like directly 'getting' the data from their server or smthing like that)

Comment: It could if you want to. But the fetching from the link can be done again in any language as well. Today Node.js is slow going to a general purpose language. So, in C you'd probably use curl to fetch the data and then operate, but node will have some inbuilt request methods, apart from that no much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Node JS helps you to run backend logic, which is written on Javascript Language.

For example, in PHP, when you write backend code, you need some kind of application which will get all clients requests and run specific code to handle it. In PHP it will be done via Apache Server. In Java it will be done via Glassfish/JBoss/Tomcat.

Node JS is something like them, but for Javascript code.